# Change IIS 7 application physical path programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, appcmd

I want to change the physical path of an application running on my IIS 7 from another application that runs on my IIS . I tried to do this via appcmd.exe. However, this seems to be impossible due to lack of authorization from the asp.net application.

That is basically what I'm trying to do

```
   private static string Execute(string IISAppName, string NewIISPath)
   {
        var winPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
        var appcmdPath = Path.Combine(winPath, "system32", "inetsrv/appcmd.exe");

        var arg = "set app /app.name:\"" + IISAppName + "\" /[path='/'].physicalPath:" + NewIISPath;

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(appcmdPath, arg)
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        var textResult = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        return textResult;
   }
```

textResult is an empty string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The AppPool for the ASP.NET site would have to be configured to run as a user with admin privilege on the box to execute that script.  In almost all cases, this is a bad idea for security reasons.